# Referencing another field in a domain function (Odoo12)

Tags: field, odoo, lookup

I want to restrict the account lookup (domain) based on the value entered in GL Prefix (I'll actually use some wildcards and some other logic which I'm comfortable adding later), the problem is that I'm getting a logical True or False value returned by self.x_poLineGLprefix rather than the value in the field.   How do I get the actual data value of x_poLineGLprefix?

```
class QuickPOLine(models.Model): 
_name = 'purchase.order.line' 
_inherit = 'purchase.order.line' 

x_poLineGLprefix = fields.Char(string='GL Prefix') 
x_poLineGLaccount = fields.Many2one( 
'account.account', string="Line Item Expense Account", 
domain=lambda self: [('code', '=', self.x_poLineGLprefix)])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add dynamic domain to achieve this based on any field. In @api.onchange() function you can return domain for many2one. To add dynamic domain you can refer this [link](https://aasimania.wordpress.com/2014/04/15/creating-dynamic-many2one-field-with-onchange-function-in-openerp/). If you are using both many2one fields refer this [link.](http://learnopenerp.blogspot.com/2016/10/onchange-many2one-filed-in-odoo.html)

Comment: If I use @api.onchange() how to I ensure I have the correct value when the form opens with an existing value (eg. previously set)?

Comment: @Mark you can use any python debugger to check values inside function, if you're using pycharm add breakpoint to check values

Comment: OK, I've installed pycharm, I can edit the files, and set a breakpoint, but how do I connect it to a running odoo instance?  I'm guessing that I can execute the application with the web browser, then at the breakpoint see the variables from the console in the pycharm IDE?

Comment: @Mark refer this https://www.cybrosys.com/blog/how-to-configure-pycharm-for-odoo-development-in-ubuntu to setup pycharm

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
@api.onchange('x_poLineGLprefix')
def onchange_x_poLineGLprefix(self):

    if self.x_poLineGLprefix:
         return {'domain': {
            'x_poLineGLaccount': [('code', '=', self.x_poLineGLprefix)]
        }}
```

Comment: Thank you, this does work.  It is only called on the changing of the field, so if the field is already set it doesn't work.  Is there an explanation as to why I can't reference the other fields directly from domain resolving function as entered in the question?